# Cannot run Starspace using bash in Google Colab

Tags: python, bash, nlp, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run this code in google colab.

```
%%bash
./Starspace/starspace train \
-trainFile "data/prepared_train.tsv" \
-model model/stackoverflow_duplicate \
-trainMode = 3 \
-adagrad true \
-ngrams 1 \
-epoch 5 \
-dim 100 \
-similarity "cosine" \
-minCount 2 \
-verbose true \
-fileFormat labelDoc \
-negSearchLimit 10 \
-lr 0.05 \
-thread 10
```

But every time I get this error `Provided argument without a dash!`.
 And some instruction about how to use. Actually I tried to use sample codes in Facebook Github repository, but I get same error.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `Starspace` is root folder of library and `starspace` file to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is causing you trouble `-trainMode = 3`, I think it should be `-trainMode 3` without the `=`

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove quotes in file-names, in model name and in fileFormat:

```
######### TRAINING HAPPENING HERE #############
%%bash
./Starspace/starspace train \
-trainFile data/train_prepare.tsv \
-model Starspace_embeddings \
-trainMode 3 \
-adagrad true \
-ngrams 1 \
-epoch 5 \
-dim 100 \
-similarity "cosine" \
-minCount 2 \
-verbose true \
-fileFormat labelDoc \
-negSearchLimit 10 \
-lr 0.05
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I was using "! ./starspace train..." without specifying the directory name but it showed my mistake.